# Can't boot to bootcamp windows anymore

Tags: bootcamp, windows, disk-utility, startup, partition

I think I made a big mistake: I wanted to boot to ubuntu from my usbstick, therefore I used the ppa mactel-boot and I could boot into ubuntu (this tutorial: https://medium.com/@mmiglier/ubuntu-installation-on-usb-stick-with-pure-efi-boot-mac-compatible-469ad33645c9). But then Windows 10 disappeared from the boot menu. So I installed rEFInd and I could see Windows, but wasn't able to boot into it. Then I tried several things, which I had seen on the net, but nothing solved my problem. I think it also made it worse.

I use a MacBook Air (Early 2015).

This is my output for diskutil list:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         80.7 GB    disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS                         40.5 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +80.7 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            77.4 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 18.8 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.2 GB     disk1s4
```

And this one using

```
sudo gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=121332826112; sectorsize=512; blocks=236978176
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Malformed MBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 236978175
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     409640  157519832      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  157929472   79048671      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header
```

Windows 10 is installed on disk0s3.

I hope you can help me.

Big thanks

Answer (score 1):

Now I tried another thing, and it looks like this right now:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         80.7 GB    disk0s2
   3:                        EFI                         40.5 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +80.7 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            77.7 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 18.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
```

and this

```
sudo gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk0
Password:
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=121332826112; sectorsize=512; blocks=236978176
gpt show: /dev/disk0: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 236978175
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     409640  157519832      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  157929472   79048671      3  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header
```

anyone out there who can help me?

The Windows partition even doesn't appear in the disk utility, only in the terminal via diskutil list